Code that runs RStudio's "Republish" button
I am working with a .Rmd file in RStudio. I have published a html file to RStudio's RPubs website. I will be republishing the same file to the same RPubs URL regularly. To do this I can press the 'Republish' button in the Viewer pane of RStudio.
But instead of pressing the 'Republish' button each time I want to republish, can I republish the file using code that is run at the end of the .Rmd file?

Have you tried rsconnect::rpubsUpload?
